# Can't understand a variable in the formula used to determine CDTY to set duty cycle of PWM on cortex M3 (SAM3X8E)

Tags: arduino, pwm, cortex-m3, duty-cycle

I want to generate complementary PWM on an Arduino due. For that purpose I am programming the cortex M3 using the PWMC library. In order to set the duty cycle I have to set a value in CDTY channel register of the Cortex M3.

The formula for calculating the duty cycle of a center aligned PWM is given in the SAM3X datasheet as,

[image]

Now I don't know what is the value of the variable "fchannel_x_clock" in this formula. If I get to know that, I can easily find the value of the CDTY to get my desired duty cycle using the above formula.

Link to the complete datasheet: http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-11057-32-bit-Cortex-M3-Microcontroller-SAM3X-SAM3A_Datasheet.pdf

The formula above is in the PWM section of the data sheet.

Comment: Other than the frequency of the clock for channel x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"fchannel_x_clock" is the frequency of the clock that you select when you program the PWM clock generator for that channel.

Take a look at section "38.6.1 - PWM Clock Generator" in that datasheet that you linked to.

Comment: Mark I dont think it is the frequency of the clock I have selected. The frequency of clock is 42MHz, and if I use this value to find the value of CDTY for a certain duty cycle I dont get a reasonable value for CDTY (the value comes out to be too large.)